# How can we include custom labels/annotations of K8s objects in Prometheus metrics?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kube-state-metrics

For example I have StatefulSet with custom labels/annotations applied on it.

Everyone mentions these two metrics should be used, because `kube-state-metrics` should generate labels/annotations as well.

```
kube_statefulset_annotations
kube_statefulset_labels
```

The thing is, I can see only default ones (`job`,`instance`, `namespace`,...) but not additionally added labels/annotations.

Example of the manifest I am testing with:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  annotations:
    label_network: "111"
  labels:
    app: testing-labels
    label_STATEFULSET_LABEL: "111"
    label_network: "111"
  name: testing-labels
  namespace: sre-test
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: testing-labels
  serviceName: testing-labels-headless
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: testing-labels
        label_network: "111"
```

I've added so many different labels/annotations but the `kube_statefulset_labels{statefulset='testing-labels'}` returns:

> kube_statefulset_labels{container="kube-rbac-proxy-main", instance="10.2.23.229:8443", job="kube-state-metrics", namespace="sre-test", prometheus="aws-monitoring/k8s", prometheus_replica="prometheus-k8s-1", statefulset="testing-labels"}

...which certainly doesn't contain any extra label. Any idea would be helpful?

#### Versions:

- kube-state-metrics:v2.5.0
- kube-rbac-proxy:v0.12.0

Answer (score 5):

In order to get custom metrics within `kube_statefulset_labels` we need to add

`--metric-labels-allowlist` as a flag in kube-state-metrics. ([docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/cli-arguments.md#available-options))

In this particular example it would be:

```
--metric-labels-allowlist=statefulsets=[label_network]
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess you are referring to these metrics.
https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/statefulset-metrics.md

According to description I would expect a list with all labels in following format.

```
statefulset=<statefulset-name>
namespace=<statefulset-namespace>
label_STATEFULSET_LABEL=<STATEFULSET_LABEL>
```

Guess it could help when you share some more details.

Maybe the manifest of you statefullset and what you get when calling the metric.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've added the manifest and what I get as a response.

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you try to let the labelname end with "_labels". Found some Info here:https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/issues/1411

Comment: I've tried that as well, but didn't help unfortunately

Comment: maybe it is really an issue on kube-state-metrics side. I've raised an github issue as well: https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/issues/1852